# Android: What if backup schedule missed?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have a schedule set at 3 AM everyday for backup. During this time, it takes a local backup followed by a cloud backup to Google Drive. My question is:

If internet is not available at 3 AM, cloud backup will not take place. So if there is always no internet at 3 AM, cloud backup will NEVER take place.

Is there any workaround for this??

Comment: Is this using the Google Drive application for Android provided by Google or using your own application which uses the Google Drive API?

Comment: I am using my own application using Google Drive SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [Completion Events](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/completion) can help with your implementation.

> **Failure** - This status indicates that the action associated with this
>   event has permanently failed to be applied to the server. The content
>   or metadata that failed to be applied to the server can be retrieved
>   using the CompletionEvent's `getModifiedContentsInputStream` or
>   `getModifiedMetadataChangeSet`, allowing you to try to apply them to the
>   server at a later time.

Since you are scheduling an upload, you can check for **Failures** through the **EventService** and then just implement your code to retry the upload on intervals of your choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SwagBomb. Could you also help me out with this SO ticket: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327532/android-get-driveid-for-restore. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I took an alternate approach. I defined a receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml` as:

```
<receiver android:name="com.xyz.abc.Receiver"
    android:exported="false"
    android:process=":remote" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This will trigger whenever there is a change is network connectivity. Then in `onReceive()` if a backup is required, I start my upload process. This way, I save on unnecessary bandwidth consumption.

Thanks for your help everyone!